# Why I am getting wrong cursor position when scaling entire body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm scaling the entire  using a CSS scale transform. The problem is that I get the wrong cursor position. I want to create a new div where the cursor is clicked but div is being created in wrong position.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css({
        transform: 'scale(0.5,0.5)'
    });
    var k = 1;
    $('.container').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
        var top = e.pageY;
        var left = e.pageX;
        $('<div />', {
            id: 'temp' + k
        }).css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: top + 'px',
            left: left + 'px',
            width: '50px',
            height: '50px',
            border: '1px solid red'
        }).appendTo('.container');
        k++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to divide your CursorPos with your scale factor.

Comment: Sorry Moltiply with your factor

Comment: @mohamed div is not created where the cursor is exactly clicked position. div is created in wrong position

Comment: so you are saying i should multiply top * 0.5.. am i right??

Comment: You just try the code which i sent here plzz and tell me the solution